# Recharts Customized XAxis name

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, recharts, react-native-web

I am just getting started learning React and React Native for Web these days. I tried to make a LineChart by using Recharts Library. I expected that the all XAxis name should be shown in the graph; 10시, 11시 ... 24시.

This is my LineData. name is XAsis label name and UV is its value.

```
let lineData = [
    { name: "10시", uv: 44 },
    { name: "11시", uv: 32 },
    { name: "12시", uv: 14 },
    { name: "13시", uv: 14 },
    { name: "14시", uv: 14 },
    { name: "15시", uv: 34 },
    { name: "16시", uv: 4 },
    { name: "17시", uv: 54 },
    { name: "18시", uv: 14 },
    { name: "19시", uv: 0 },
    { name: "20시", uv: 34 },
    { name: "21시", uv: 54 },
    { name: "22시", uv: 14 },
    { name: "23시", uv: 24 },
    { name: "24시", uv: 34 },
  ];
```

In the Linechart I am using ResponsiveContainer, XAsis, and YAxis for customizing the graph.

This is my code

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={250}>
              <LineChart
                data={lineData}
                margin={{ top: 20, right: 0, left: -15, bottom: 5 }}
              >
                <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="red" />
                <XAxis
                  dataKey="name"
                  tick={{ fontSize: 10 }}
                  // width="-100"
                  // ticks={[
                  //   10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
                  // ]}
                  // domain={[10, 24]}
                />
                <YAxis tick={{ fontSize: 10 }} ticks={[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]} />
              </LineChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
```

What I mentioned above, the XAsis name should be shown in the graph all of them but part of name only show like this.
[image]

10시, 12시, 14시, 16시, 18시, 20시, 22시, 23시 are disapeared.
Could you help me with what part do I missing or wrong?
I would be really appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you set the width 100% for ResponsiveContainer and you are rendering this graph in narrow screen, Recharts automatically cut some x-axis values.

Have you tried adding interval props for XAxis?
If you set `interval={0}` in XAxis component, you can see all the x-axis values in the screen even it is not wide enough.

```js
<XAxis
  dataKey="name"
  tick={{ fontSize: 10 }}
  interval={0}
/>
```

Comment: The index is totally working! thank you so much!